# Array sorting for Budget range in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have a Two PHP arrays as Below

Array 1 - Budget Start

```
Array
(
    [0] => 25000
    [1] => 30000
    [2] => 35000
    [3] => 15900
)
```

Array 2 - Budget End

```
Array
(
    [0] => 40000
    [1] => 50000
    [2] => 60000
    [3] => 55000
)
```

I want to Filter the Budget range which the user is actually looking for.For the above the budget range is **35000 For Budget Start and 40000 for Budget End.**

The Budget Start is Calculated by comparing every budget start with every other budget start so that  Budget Start should be between Budget Start and Budget End

Budget Start 35000 because

```
25000 <= 35000 < 40000
30000 <= 35000 < 50000
35000 <= 35000 < 60000
15900 <= 35000 < 55000
```

Budget End 40000 because

```
25000 < 40000 <= 40000
30000 < 40000 <= 50000
35000 < 40000 <= 60000
15900 < 40000 <= 55000
```

Is there some way to resolve this.

Thanks for Reply

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you're trying to do.  You want the smallest start and end values that are between each pair?  What *should* the answer be in this case?  Should the 70000+90000 be ignored, or should there be no correct answer?

Comment: Yes I should Ignore 70000 and 90000 in the above case

Comment: So how do you know it should be ignored?  Do you just want whichever answer will satisfy the most of these at once?  What if they're all disjoint like (40000,60000,80000), (50000,70000,90000)?

Comment: Ok forget the 70000 and 90000

Comment: why not set your data as single array ? i.e. `$Budget=array(array(25000,40000),array(30000,50000))`

Comment: what is user's input and output ?

Comment: do you want to find out (35000, and 40000) using such algorithm?

Comment: The User input is above array to a code block and the output should be two variables 35000 For Budget Start and 40000 for Budget End.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$start = Array(25000,30000,35000,15900);

$end = Array(40000,50000,60000,55000);


foreach($start as $val){
    $cnt = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($start); $i++){
        if($start[$i] <= $val && $val < $end[$i]){
            $cnt++;
        }
        if($cnt == count($start)){
            $start_budget = $val;
        }
    }
}

foreach($end as $val){
    $cnt = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($end); $i++){
        if($start[$i] < $val && $val <= $end[$i]){
            $cnt++;
        }
        if($cnt == count($end)){
            $end_budget = $val;
        }
    }
}

echo $start_budget;
echo "<br>";
echo $end_budget;
?>
```